# Characteristic function of a singular distribution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have a singular distribution $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$, i.e. the CDF $F$ is continuous and its set of growth points has measure $0$. One example for $F$ could be the Cantor function. My question relates to the characteristic function of such a distribution: $$\varphi(t)=\int_0^1\exp(itx)dF(x)$$
Is it always true that $\varphi(t)\xrightarrow{t \rightarrow\infty}0$?

For the Cantor function, this seems to be the case: $\varphi(t)=\exp(it/2)\prod_{j=0}^\infty\cos\left(t/3^j\right)$. Although please correct me if my assumption of the convergence of this function is incorrect. (Edit: It was incorrect, see my answer)

Comment: Do you have a proof for the claim that $\phi (t) \to 0$ for the Cantor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r \in (0,1/2)$. A beautiful Theorem by R. Salem (see [1]) shows that if $F_r$ is the distribution function corresponding  to the natural (singular) measure on the middle $1-2r$ set, then the Fourier transform $\widehat{F_r}(t)$ tends to 0 as $t \to \infty$ for almost every $r \in (0,1/2)$. The only exceptions occur when $1/r$ is an integer or a Pisot number, i.e., an algebraic integer with all its conjugates in the open unit disk.  (The Cantor function is $F_{1/3}$, so it is one of the exceptions.)

[1] Salem, Raphaël. Algebraic numbers and Fourier analysis. Wadsworth Publishing Company, 1983.

Comment: Beautiful! Unfortunately it will be hard to apply this to my original problem, but maybe you have an idea of where to point me if you don't mind. 
Assume $A_t$ is a square-integrable continuous finite variation process on $[0,1]$, i.e. it decays into continuous and monotonous $A_t=A_t^+-A_t^-$. Then path wise, examining the limit in the question for $\int_0^1\exp(i\omega t)dA_t$ amounts to my original question. So if we are unlucky, all of the paths might lie in the case where the characteristic function doesn't vanish. Do you have an idea of why any reasonable process shouldn't exhibit this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, since my intuition about the characteristic function of the Cantor function decaying was wrong. It is constant on the sequence $t_i=3^i4\pi$ and has a value of about -0.07 (computed with Wolfram alpha)